# Trying to figure out what the base language is

Tags: plc

Quick question (maybe).

I'm a process control engineer starting a new job with a company that uses Novatech software/hardware for SCADA and Operations. Novatech utilizes a programming language it calls SABL code. It looks very much like a hodge-podge between VB and Python. I'm trying to figure out if it's really just a base language adapted to their needs. What's throwing me off is it uses 'Else If' like VB but has mandatory indentation like Python. Is there a language that uses 'Else If' not 'elif' like Python or 'elsif' like Ruby but also has mandatory indentation?

If I can figure out the base language, I can put some study into the language and speed up my ability to use it proficiently. Otherwise, I'll end up in some class that's oriented on a lot of trifle information I don't need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t have an answer for you, but my guess would be that it does use a base language or syntax akin to VB. A similar, proprietary language existed for ArchestrA back when I was doing Control Systems development. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. It does seem very much like a proprietary mix with mostly VB syntax. It would have been nice to carry a couple reference books with me and run with it, but looks like I'll be accessing help files and trying to catch myself up on it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sequence And Batch Language (SABL®) is a proprietary language created by GSE Systems that was later purchased by Novatech.  It is [trademarked](https://trademarks.justia.com/757/48/sabl-75748105.html) by Novatech and GSE.  SABL® is based on (or conforms to) the [ANSI/ISA-88](https://www.isa.org/standards-and-publications/isa-standards/isa-standards-committees/isa88) and [ANSI/ISA-106](https://www.isa.org/standards-and-publications/isa-standards/isa-standards-committees/isa106) standards and is used in Novatech's [D/3](https://www.novatechautomation.com/products/d-3-control-system) Distributed Control System (DSP) software.

In other words, it does not have a base language and is much older than Python.  It does conform to certain ISA standards but is solely used by one company who owns all rights and trademarks to it.